# tornado deploy django and the log repeat output

Tags: django, logging, tornado

In my project i deployed my django-project with tornado server, and my tornado main function is:

```
def main():
    tornado.options.options.logging = None
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Zero.settings'
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(application)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(container, xheaders=True)
    http_server.listen(tornado.options.options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

When i use `tornado.options.options.logging = None` to disabled tornado logging output, but it still output the log message in my console with twice, my django logging config is:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
       'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(threadName)s] [%(name)s:%(funcName)s] [%(levelname)s]- %(message)s'}
    },
    'filters': {
    },
    'handlers': {
        'error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log', 'error.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

The final result is:

```
2018-06-15 17:40:55,724 [MainThread] [base_views:get] [INFO]- get message correct
INFO:base_views:get message correct
```

so what can i do to solve this problem.
Thank U.

Comment: Why are you running Django on Tornado? This architectures is very inefficient.

Comment: @xyres Because i need a lot of HTTP persistent connection and Tornado can do that easily. And the uwsgi server will restart when many requests processed, so i choose the Tornado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only configured the `django` logger, not the root logger. When Tornado sees that the root logger is not configured, it adds its own last-resort handler (using `logging.basicConfig` instead of `tornado.log`). Because of the way python loggers propagate, this results in any other loggers being duplicated.

When you use `tornado.options.options.logging = None`, you should make sure that you configure the root logger yourself, or configure all of your other handlers with `propagate=False`. In this case, move the `loggers.django` section of your config to a new `root` section:

```
'handlers': {...}
'root': {
  'handlers': ['console'],
  'level': 'INFO',
},
```